# Vundle doesn't load the theme

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vundle

This is my `.vimrc` located under `$HOME/.vimrc`. I've installed Vundle.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'dracula/dracula-theme'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

I'm able to execute `:PluginInstall` successfully installing `dracula-theme`. Unfortunately the theme is not applied and the style remains unchanged? Any clues?

Comment: Please do not cross post! http://stackoverflow.com/q/39924372/5048383

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following to your .vimrc

```
syntax on
colorscheme dracula
```

Comment: Add syntax on and now it works

Comment: I've added only `syntax on` and now it works. I've added also this plugin `http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-airline` but it doesn't work. Should I also add anything more in the config?

Comment: I've also added other plugins like `fatih/vim-go` `scrooloose/nerdtree` but without any effect. why am I missing?